# Error coming as "Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null"

Tags: javascript, html-table

I am generating html table from Javascript and assign as InnerHTML to a div tag, but its giving an error:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null"

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="fieldlist-vertical-title" style="color:white;left:0px;display:none;" id="rosterlegend">Some text</div>
<script>
   function generateLegend()
       {
       var fullTable ='' fullTable='<Table><TR><Table><TR bgcolor=#FF5733><TD>MM</TD>
       <TD>01:00 to 21:30</TD></TR></Table></TR></Table>'
       document.getElementById('rosterlegend').innerHTML = fullTable
       }
   generateLegend();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

> Error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Comment: Does the element with `id="rosterlegend"` exists?

Comment: Most of the times this happens when you try to run the script when the DOM is not completely loaded. What happens if you run `document.getElementById('rosterlegend')` in the console after the page loads?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Comment: @CarlBinalla Yes,  <div id="rosterlegend"> </div>

Comment: Did you put the script before `</body>`?

Comment: @CristianS.When i run in console it shows like this : <div id="rosterlegend">                    </div>

Comment: @Kanishka please add your HTML to the question

Comment: @CarlBinalla the script is inside the Body tag after the div tag

Comment: You call the function immediately. The DOM is not not loaded.

Comment: @NickParsons
<html>
<body>
    <div class="fieldlist-vertical-title" style="color:white;left:0px;display:none;" id="rosterlegend">Some text</div>
    <script>
        function generateLegend(){
            var fullTable =''

            fullTable='<Table><TR><Table><TR bgcolor=#FF5733><TD>MM</TD><TD>01:00 to 21:30</TD></TR></Table></TR></Table>'
            document.getElementById('rosterlegend').innerHTML = fullTable
        } 
        generateLegend();  
    </script>
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 2):

Try changing to something like this, so we ensure the HTML DOM has completed loading first. 
Use ES6 template string instead of plain strings!

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  generateLegend();
});

function generateLegend() {
  fullTable = `<Table>
                 <TR>
                   <Table>
                     <TR bgcolor=#FF5733>
                       <TD>MM</TD>
                       <TD>01:00 to 21:30</TD>
                     </TR>
                     <TR bgcolor=#FFFFFF>
                       <TD>EVVV</TD>
                       <TD>09:00 to 05:30</TD>
                     </TR>
                  </Table>
                 </TR>
               </Table>`;

  document.getElementById('rosterlegend').innerHTML = fullTable;
}
```

```html
<div id="rosterlegend">
  <div>
```

Comment: If you look at the level of question, the next question by her is probably going to be "my code doesn't work in IE 11".

Answer (score 0):

Removes new lines and extra spaces in the HTML String.

Rest of your code works fine!
However it is not a god practice.
Ideally you have to wait for the window to be loaded.

```
window.onload(){
  generateLegend();
}
```

```js
function generateLegend() {
   var fullTable = " <Table><TR><Table><TR bgcolor=#FF5733><TD>MM</TD><TD>01:00 to 21:30</TD></TR><TR bgcolor=#FFFFFF><TD>EVVV</TD><TD>09:00 to 05:30</TD></TR></Table></TR></Table>";

   document.getElementById('rosterlegend').innerHTML = fullTable;
}
generateLegend();
```

```html
<div id="rosterlegend">Some text</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you are trying to access your div with the `id` of "rosterlegend" before the DOM has loaded. This means that when your javascript tries to access your element it cannot. One way you can fix this is by adding the `load` or `DOMContentLoaded` event listener to your element, where the function will fire once your HTML (including images if you use the `load` event) and window has loaded. This way your javascript will know about your HTML.

See working example below:

```js
function generateLegend() {
   var fullTable = " <Table><TR><Table><TR bgcolor=#FF5733><TD>MM</TD><TD>01:00 to 21:30</TD></TR><TR bgcolor=#FFFFFF><TD>EVVV</TD><TD>09:00 to 05:30</TD></TR></Table></TR></Table>";

   document.getElementById('rosterlegend').innerHTML = fullTable;
}

window.addEventListener("load", generateLegend); // call your function when the window has loaded
```

```html
<div id="rosterlegend"></div>
```

Comment: Only problem with onload is that we rely on being the only caller.

Comment: @Bibberty what do you mean by "only caller"?

Comment: When we do `window.onload = myEvent` we can be overridden by a subsequent script saying `window.onload = myOtherEvent` so might be better to consider `window|document.addEventListener('load', myFunction)` as this is multi subscriber.

Comment: @Bibberty ah, I never thought of that. I've updated my answer, thanks ;)